# Extract multiple years worth of data from .nc file using shapefiles

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, netcdf

I have a .nc file which contains monthly data for southern Africa over 30 years (aka 360 timesteps). I want to mask/extract the data using 13 different shapefiles (of agroecological zones in southern Africa), so that each of the 13 resultant portions of the original data also contains 360 timesteps, just as the original .nc datafile does.

I have tried to use the extract by mask tool, but the result of using it renders a raster layer with only one timestep. How can I cut the multidimensional raster so for each agroecological zone it remains multidimensional, i.e. has 360 timesteps?

I also tried to use 'extract' from rgdal in R Studio, but this didn't work.